# Can't connect to shared network printer with new router

Tags: windows, router, printer, network-printer

Recently, we got a new router for our home network. However, this seems to have caused problems with printing. We have one desktop computer, connected to the router via a ethernet cable, which our printer is connected to. The rest of the computers are connected wirelessly. When trying to find a network printer to connect to on one of the computers connected wirelessly, nothing shows up.

The desktop computer is running Windows 7, and I have unsuccessfully tried connecting to it using Windows 7 and Windows 8. However, I was able to connect to using Ubuntu 14.04, using Samba and the device URI smb://desktop-ip/printer-name.

Comment: This is related to if the printer has been shared through Windows and that the computer itself is discoverable on your network. Have you set up the home sharing/sharing on the computer the printer is attached to?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I've checked the sharing settings and the printer is set to be shared among computers on the same homegroup/network.

Comment: Has Windows itself been set to be part of a homegroup/network? Windows firewall must allow the computer to be discoverable.

Comment: All of the Windows computers involved had been set to be a part of the same homegroup.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to connect to the printer by going to Add a Printer -> Printer I want isn't found -> Add shared printer by name, and then using the IP address of the computer where the printer is connected. It doesn't work if I use the actual computer name instead of the IP address. I tried doing this after seeing [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107310) when I was attempting to get printing working with Ubuntu.